# Usage of 'for' before 'how many'

Tags: grammar

Do I need to use **for** in the following question?

- **For** How many days was the war of Mahabharat fought?

Comment: It's needed for proper syntax.

Comment: _For_ is obligatory if you want to use _was fought_ instead of _lasted_ (where _for_ is optional) or _took_ (where _for_ is not allowed). However, you can also strand it at the end of the sentence: _How  many days was the war of Mahabharat fought for?_

Comment: Then which one is correct: 'How many days have you been here for?' or 'How many days have you been here?